# Why do my airpods show up on Find My as "No location found" even though they are right next to me?

Tags: find-my-iphone, airpods, find-my

I go into "Find My" app and I see my AirPods listed but it says "no location found" or "offline" even though they are fully charged and sitting right next to me (both the actual AirPods and the case)

Does anyone know how I can reset this so it can properly track these (as I often forget where I put them)?

Comment: 1. Are the AirPods in your case? 2. Have you connected them (recently) to one of your Apple devices linked to the same icloud account you’re using with “find my”?